# How to translate the selected text in Windows using Google translate?

Tags: windows, popups, translation, google-translate

When I select a text in the Android system, it shows an option to translate the selected text using [Google translate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.translate&hl=en) (my translation pops up).

Now, how to use Google translate service in the same way (or using hotkeys) to translate the selected text in Windows without opening a browser or the main window of a dictionary?

P.S. Maybe some apps like [GoldenDict](http://goldendict.org/) is helpful, but when I add the following address:

```
https://translate.google.com/#en/ar/%GDWORD%
```

It shows nothing! [see this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUNvL.png)

Comment: I suggest you to try GoldenDict unstable version from here https://github.com/goldendict/goldendict/wiki/Early-Access-Builds-for-Windows If I remember correctly version from official site is very dated and has bugs which were fixed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I strongly advise you [QTranslate](https://quest-app.appspot.com/home).

Its a free windows app, that translate selected text by pressing hotkey.
Program support many translate services like Google, Babylon and much more.
I think this is must have app for all, who need read text on not in native language.